# Completions of number fields at the same prime

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

This is probably obvious, but I don't quite see it.

Archimedean completions of different number fields are always isomorphic to the same $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Is the same true in the non-archimedean case?

More precisely, llet $K$, $L$ be non-isomorphic number fields, and $\mathfrak{p}$ a nonarchimedean prime  of both $K$ and $L$.

> When is it true that $K_\mathfrak{p}\cong L_\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: No, there are many such completions; they correspond to finite extensions of the $p$-adic fields $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (so e.g. they differ in which integers have square roots).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So all completions of non-isomorphic number fields (at the same prime) are non-isomorphic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm just saying they're not necessarily isomorphic.

Comment: What do you mean when you call $\mathfrak p$ a prime of both $K$ and $L$? How are we to compare primes of $K$ and those of $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qiaochu Yuan has said in his comments, maybe yes, maybe no. Just look at two quadratic number fields. Say $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3}\,)$ and $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt5\,)$. Then their completions at $2$ are isomorphic, the unique quadratic unramified extension of $\Bbb Q_2$. At $3$, $K$ gives you a ramified extension of $\Bbb Q_3$, but $L$ gives you the unramified extension of $\Bbb Q_3$. It’s just the reverse at $5$: $K$ has unramified completion, $L$ has ramified completion. More interesting starting with $7$, for there, $-3\equiv4$, a square, so that the $7$-adic completion of $K$ is not even a field, it’s the product of two copies of $\Bbb Q_7$, while the $7$-adic completion of $L$ is again unramified.

In this description, I’ve kept secret the important role that Quadratic Reciprocity plays in the story, and that’s for you to find out on your own.